# Android activity crashing immediately after start

Tags: android, runtime, onclicklistener

I've been working on developing an app for a while, and everything was going well. However, when I added an onCLickListener for a  button in one of my .xml files(not main.xml), it started crashing as soon as I tried to open it in the emulator. All the code for the onClickListener is the same as for the other two buttons I have. here's the code for my problematic listener:

```
    Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(bt3listener);


    private OnClickListener bt3listener = new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
};
```

The only way that any of this code differs from my other onClickListeners is that it references a button in a different file than main.xml. It crashes before displays any of the ui except a black screen with my project name on the top, and gives me a prompt that says "un

Comment: You run this applicatin with code and the eclipse don't give any error.
Great.
you use the variable which is declare after the use and program will run successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for a button in one of my .xml files(not main.xml),

It have to be int the layout you set with `setContentView()`, in order to retrieve it with `findViewById()` using `this` or use an `inflater` in order to get the layout in which the `Button` is declared, and use the returned `view` with `findViewById()`.

```
viewReturnedByInflater.findViewById()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise the OnClickListener before you assign it to the button.

Comment: "button3.setOnClickListener(bt3listener);" This must come after the initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private OnClickListener bt3listener = new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
};
Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
button3.setOnClickListener(bt3listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

It gives you the error because when `Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);`
 it tries to find the button, but since the button is in another xml layout, it crashes.

You should infalte the other layout or add the button on the main layout